# RouteChangeStart event fired on initial index.html page load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The route change event is fired on the initial page load itself, ideally i want to fire when the user go to the next page from the initial page not on the initial page load.

Here I have bound the directive "meeee" to the elements and in the link function of the directive I put the callback for routeChangeStart 
event.

In which I want to fire the callback to remove the elements from the current page with directive "meeee" when user goes to the next page.
But "routeChangeStart" event is fired for the current page itself, removing all the "meeee" elements at the initial load itself ,

please see this plunkr code http://plnkr.co/edit/h7nLME7YW7dI8qaBk1in?p=preview

> Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
            <div ng-controller="parentCtrl" class="">

                <div ng-view>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="d1-Me1" class="meeee">
                Meee1
            </div>
            <div id="d1-Me2" class="meeee">
                Meee2
            </div>

            <div id="d1-Me3" class="meeee">
                Meee3
            </div>
        </body>

</html>
```

> App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.controller('parentCtrl',['$scope','$window','$location',function ($scope,$window,$location) {


}]);
myApp.config(function($locationProvider,$routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/p1', {
      templateUrl:'page1.html',
    })
    .when('/p2', {
       templateUrl:'page2.html',
    })
    .when('/p3', {
      templateUrl:'partials/page3.html',
    })
    .when('/default', {
      templateUrl:'default.html',
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/default'
    });
});

myApp.directive("meeee",['$rootScope','$location', function ($rootScope, $location){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
            $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
                console.log('attr["id"]: '+attr["id"]);
                elm.remove();
            });
            elm.detach();
            angular.element("body").append(elm);
        }
    };
}]);
```

> default.html

```
<a href="#/p1">
    Page1
</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#/p2">
    Page2
</a>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#/p3">
    Page3
</a>
```

> Page1.html

In Page One

```
<div id="p1-Me1" class="meeee">
    Page 1 Meee1
</div>
<div id="p1-Me2" class="meeee">
    Page 1 Meee2
</div>

<div id="p1-Me3" class="meeee">
    Page 1 Meee3
</div>
```

> page2.html

```
<p>In Page Two</p>
```

> page3.html

```
<p>In Page Three</p>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter so that if it this the first pageload, it doesn't apply?